# Do web forms page class names need to be unique?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Building a medium complexity single page app.

My project has similar but different functionality is some areas such that the logical (as in reasonable) name for pages overlaps. To organize the project I place the different functionality in sub folders and this has the side effect of allowing me to name the page files the same.

Consider this example:

```
../mypage.aspx
../subdir1/mypage.aspx
../subdir2/mypage.aspx
```

Each myPage.aspx has this (snippet):

```
<%@ Page Inherits="mynamespace.mypage" %>
```

And each code behing has this:

```
Public Class mypage
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
End Class
```

It occurs to me this may get confusing, the alternative would be to make up some prefix or suffix to distinguish the files.

```
../mypage.aspx
../mypageFN1.aspx or ../FN1/mypageFN1.aspx
```

While I may choose to do that my question is does naming pages the same cause any problems when running the website?

What if a user could have two of the pages open at once (as in tabs)?

My thought is the class names only exist during page fetch operations on the server so there is no possibility for collision, but I am not confident in that assessment.

Comment: As long as they aren't both in the same namespace then you shouldn't have an issue

Comment: `Does naming pages the same cause any problems when running the website?` have you tried this and what happened?

Comment: @Codexer - nothing obviously bad happens, but occasionally I load a page with an identical element id, it loads but odd things happen, understandable.

Comment: If you have identical element id's then yes, you would definitely have some odd affects. On the other hand as @SeanT has pointed out, if they are not in the same namespace then it would be fine.

Comment: i agree, different namespaces is the answer.